# Merging 2 images together in winRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Anyone any idea on how to merge 2 rectangle images inside one large image? Naturally keeping track of the Bounds so they are side by side and don't overlap...

This has a good starting point http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/490b9c01-db4b-434f-8aff-d5c495e67e55 on how crop images and setting it to another, but not on how to merge several images.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to align images within a larger image?  What criteria do you want to use when aligning them (matching on content, centering, etc...)?

Comment: I want to create something like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Hand_ball_4_square.svg so if I have 2 images, the top 2 cells should be filled in. If I have 1 image, the complete square should filled etc...

Comment: That would not 'resize' the images to one... but I'll look but maybe it has the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that version 1.0 from WriteableBitmapEx finally works! So you can now use the Blit command to do this!

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/
http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/357603